# Union of two half-open intervals intersected by the rationals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $$\varepsilon = \{(a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}: a,b\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}\}$$ 
where $-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$.
Let $(a_1,b_1]\cap \mathbb{Q}\in \varepsilon$ and $(a_2,b_2]\cap \mathbb{Q}\in \varepsilon$ be not disjoint, i.e., $((a_1,b_1]\cap \mathbb{Q})\cap ((a_2,b_2]\cap \mathbb{Q})\neq \emptyset$. What is their union equal to? i.e., what is $$((a_1,b_1]\cap \mathbb{Q})\cup ((a_2,b_2]\cap \mathbb{Q}) = $$
and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:$$\left(a,b\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}$$ where $a=\min\left(a_{1},a_{2}\right)$
and $b=\max\left(b_{1},b_{2}\right)$.

Note that $\left(a_{i},b_{i}\right]\subseteq\left(a,b\right]$ for $i=1,2$ so
that $\left[\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}\right]\cup\left[\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}\right]\subseteq\left(a,b\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Conversely if $r\in\left(a,b\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ then $a_{1}<r$
or $a_{2}<r$.

If both inequalities hold then $r\in\left(a_{1},b\right]\cap\mathbb Q$ and $r\in\left(a_{2},b\right]\cap\mathbb Q$
and one of these sets is an element of $\left\{ \left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\cap\mathbb{Q},\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}\right\} $, so $r$ will be an element of the union of $\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}$
and $\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

If - let's say - $a_{1}<r<a_{2}$ then can it happen that $b_{1}<r$
as well?

No, because $b_{1}<r\leq b$ implies $r\leq b_{2}$ and this can only be true if
$\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\cap\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right]=\varnothing$.

Comment: Why is it $\min(a_1,a_2)$ and $\max(b_1,b_2)$? I just need some intuition on why that is the case. I know your answer is right but I just don't understand why without just looking at the converse.

Comment: If $x\in\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\cup\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right]$ then
it cannot be that $x>b_{1}\wedge x>b_{2}$ so $x\leq\max\left(b_{1},b_{2}\right)$.
Likewise it cannot be that $x\leq a_{1}\wedge x\leq a_{2}$ so $x>\min\left(a_{1},a_{2}\right)$.
That points in the direction of $\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\cup\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right]=\left(\min\left(a_{1},a_{2}\right),\max\left(b_{1},b_{2}\right)\right]$
which is indeed the case under the extra condition that $\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\cap\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right]\neq\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the distributive law for intersection over union:

$$\big((a_1,b_1]\cap\Bbb Q\big)\cup\big((a_2,b_2]\cap\Bbb Q\big)=\big((a_1,b_1]\cup(a_2,b_2]\big)\cap\Bbb Q\;.$$

As for $(a_1,b_1]\cup(a_2,b_2]$, that depends on the ordering of the endpoints. It is

- $(a_1,b_2]$ if $a_1\le a_2\le b_1<b_2$;
- $(a_1,b_1]$ if $a_1\le a_2<b_2\le b_1$;

and so on through the other possibilities, which I leave for you to work out. In each case, though, it is a left-open, right-closed interval.

Comment: I re-edited my question could you take a look I think it may change a view points you made.

Comment: @Wolfy: Your edit did not substantively change the question in any way; my answer still stands.